# how to disable Keyboard inputs on windows like (temporary)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio

i have problem i'm trying to do new shortcut but if i put the shortcut i made F11 then will happen is full screen , i want to disable Keyboard inputs form windows or just disable the actions form windows i mean (if i press any key i want to put the action not windows put the action)

i create application that raises the volume , i put the volume up "F11" but in google chrome F11 is full screen, there anther application if i press F11 or F10 or F9 it do something and i dont want this happen.

i'm using Visual Studio Windows forms C#

note: my application work in background (i dont want use From1_KeyUp or Down i know this code)

Thank You for help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNBS5.png)
2 pictures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoJMi.png)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to enable the F11 key for fullscreen resolutions and disable all other keys to prevent conflicts?

Comment: i dont mean Form1_KeyUp or Down i mean on windows i know how to use this code you put it first answer i mean i want to change shortcut on windows not in the (Form or my application)

Comment: Okay, so if a user presses the F11 key for fullscreen, you don't want the next F11 key command to be confused with volume or anything else? Also, if you show the code you've done so far it would be a huge help, as I'm still not sure if I follow.

Comment: mate i'm using input Simulator (input-Device-State)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Simulator, but if you show your code it would help in resolving the problem much more.

Comment: Thank You very much ( Anders ) after 2 days in tried finally its work. you are the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent keys from reaching the target application you must [use a low-level keyboard hook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) and return a non-zero value when you performed your own custom action.